# performSegue before the View is visible

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two views

```
ViewController-> Main view
LoginVC -> LogIn View
```

My initial view is ViewController which contains buttons and some text.

**What i want to achive**

Perform a segue that will transfer the view to Login if the user is not yet log in.

**What i have done**

Inside my ViewController I did a check if USER_ID is nil then if its a nil then i will perform a segue.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if Globals.USER_ID == nil{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: nil)
//            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
//                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: nil)
//            })
        }
    }
```

**What is my problem**

My Problem is whether I use viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear  to transfer view from **ViewController** to LoginVC.**ViewController** will be visible in a single second before the the login screen appears and i want to get rid of it.Can someone help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have same functionality in my App. I achieved it by checking for `userID` in `AppDelegate.swift` inside function `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

So, delete the segue and your modified code will look like as follows:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

    if Globals.USER_ID == nil{
        let loginScreen = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginScreen

    }else{
        let mainScreen = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainScreen
    }
    return true
}
```

This way you will not need any of the method like `viewDidLoad()`, `viewDidAppear()` or `viewWillAppear()`to be used for this purpose.

Just as an addition to this answer - Use the instance of AppDelegate again after logout happens. For example you should do following in logout method:

```
func logout() {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
            Globals.USER_ID = nil
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginScreen
        }
}
```

This way you can clear the userID and navigate back to login screen after the user logouts.

Comment: this is not a valid answer, he needs a generic solution not editing his AppDelegate. It does not work for any viewcontroller.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Not sure what JBarros35 meant by "does not work for any viewcontroller."